# Starting Flash Development

Tags: flash

I want to make a flash based site.

I like something like this: http://bfish.free.fr/

Is this hard? I have done a little Flash work, but I can learn.

How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

well kongregate has some good tutorials on it, mostly game oriented but you can learn some of the basics from them.

[kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/labs)

Comment: Thank You for the link. How do you lay out your presentation if you dont have the flash GUI? I like the idea of command-line tools, etc.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have a lot of experience or knowledge in Flash, I jsut posted what i knew about.